# Check if the method uses PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, system.reflection, methodbase

Is there anyway to check if a method uses PInvoke ?
I'm looping through all the methods in an assembly using MethodBase but I want to check if the method is using PInvoke.
Here is the code I'm using :

```
 foreach (MethodBase bases in mtd.GetType().GetMethods())
 {
      //check if the method is using pinvoke
 }
```

Also if it is possible how can is there a way I can check for the DLL being used and the function/entrypoint that is being called?

Comment: Turn code analysis on. It will start howling about them. :)

Comment: A questionable approach.  What if the method uses a private pinvoke declaration itself?  What's the *real* point of doing this?

Comment: It is just for debugging purpose :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check to see if a method is decorated with [DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y1600).  If so, it's using PInvoke.

```
foreach (MethodBase methodBase in mtd.GetType().GetMethods())
{
    if (methodBase.CustomAttributes.Any(cad => cad.AttributeType == typeof(DllImportAttribute))
    {
         // Method is using PInvoke
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension method:

```
    public static bool IsPinvoke(this MethodBase method)
    {
        return method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl);
    }
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, it's much faster.